# Colocar un formulario siempre al fondo C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Mi situación a resolver es la siguiente. 
Tengo un formulario "HOME" que es el form principal, a su vez tengo el formulario "B" (vamos a llamarlo así).
Pongamos nos en la situación donde ambos formularios están minimizados. Al maximizar el form "B" quisiera que se maximice también el "HOME" al fondo. 
También que al seleccionar el Home, se maximicen todas las ventanas abiertas para que quede "HOME" de fondo.
Les dejo una imagen por si aclara un poco más.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Son formularios aparte uno de otro o uno es hijo de otro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias integrar ambos formularios usando `MDI` entonces el `form home` sera el `contenedor` del `form B`

Para esto debes hacer que el `home` tenga la propiedad `IsMdiContainer` en true

Y el `form B` cuando lo inicias asignas

```
FormB frm = new FormB();
frm.MdiParent = this;
frm.Show();
```

En este caso `this` seria la instancia del `form home`

De esta forma un form estara contenido y al minimizar el home tambien los haran los forms que este contenga

Comment: En lugar de "frm.MdiContainer = this;" hay que usar "frm.MdiParent = this;"  Muchas gracias por todo.

Comment: si es verdad, ya edite el codigo asi queda correcto, igual la idea creo que sentendi a donde apuntaba